# How to validate Scopes for each controller in .Net core mvc Oauth2 bearer token

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, authorization, bearer-token

I have a .net core 2.2 app that exposes some Rest API, that must be accessed using a bearer token.

I can validate the token

```
Startup.cs/ConfigureServices
      services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                    {
                        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            RequireExpirationTime = true,
                            RequireSignedTokens = true,
                            ValidateAudience = false,
                            ValidateIssuer = false,
                            ValidateLifetime = false,
                            IssuerSigningKeys = openIdConfig.SigningKeys
                            ////Ensure the token audience matches our audience value(default true):
                            //ValidateAudience = false, //true,
                            //                          //ValidAudience = "api://default",
                        };

                    });
```

And I understood that setting ValidateAudience = true I could set a ValidAudience.

Controllers actions are decorated as follows

```
[HttpPost("/v1.0/call/msisdns/{msisdn}")]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(string msisdn, [FromBody] CallRoot callRoot)
```

The token can contain different scopes, and each controller requires a specific scope.

I can check if the token contains at least one valid scope, but I do not know how to check if it contains a scope valid for the specific controller (or action) that will handle the request.

I supposed that some overload of the Authorize attribute could help, I figured out that maybe I can map an audience/scope to a role and have the controller authorize that role, but I do not know if this could work and how to perform this mapping.

Comment: allowed scope will be stored as claims in your JWT, extract that and create a policy that requires a claim with a specific value.

Comment: `AuthorizeAttribute` is now just a placeholder. You don't inherit from it like you'd might have in ASP.NET MVC, in most scenarios. For custom authorization, you use policies. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1